# Split a line from point but with a certain distance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, line, splitting

I am using ArcGIS 10.2. I need some suggestion about this problem, maybe there is a certain tool, but I think no. I think some python code... but I do not know from where to start  :(

I have two shapefile layers: some polylines with points intersected. So, what I want to do **automatically** is to SPLIT those lines from a fixed measure (for example 10 meters) before and after this Point placed on the polyline.

The Points are on the line.

For example, if I have a 100 meters length polyline, and the point is situated in the middle, I want it split on the 40th and 60th meter.

Comment: Buffer the points by 10 metres and then intersect with the buffer.. Are the points on the lines or displaced from the lines??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buffer the points by 10 metres and then ERASE

Comment: I think this will delete any parts of the input polyline(s) covered by the erase polygon which will therefore not meet the requirements in the question. Also, "about a paragraph" is normally considered minimum length for answers (and questions) here so perhaps you can elaborate upon yours by including more words at the beginning like: "I have assumed that you wish to lose the parts of the polylines within 10m of the points. If not then my advice here may not apply."

Comment: I think 'intersect' will erase input polylines outside 10 m buffer. Thus assuming that no part of the line has to be missed, the merging of 'erase' and 'intersect' outputs seems appropriate

Comment: That's true so I recommend that you use its edit button to update your answer to incorporate something like my suggested words plus that new information.  Think of comments as being to discuss how to improve questions and answers but both the question and answer should be standalone (so that the comments can then be deleted).

Comment: YOu were right, here the steps: 1.- Buffer 10 in points. 2.- Intersect (lines with buffer).  3.- Erase (last output and lines).  4.-Merge (last output and intersection output).  Thanks!

Comment: Glad it is working. Truly sorry if I am typing in a wrong box yet again. Solution is elegant, but works if a) there is no 2nd line nearby b) line is not twisty inside buffer. Consider linear referencing